# Java Servlet download more than one file

Tags: java, web, servlets, download, webclient

I have more attachments to download instead of downloading one by one.

I need to download them by zipping these files as batched 2 or 3 files in each zip based on conditions written in the code.

The code is written to download 2 zip files but it downloaded only one zip through response.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.URLEncoder;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;


public class downloadSert extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Attachments.ZIP");
        response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.addHeader("Expires", "0");

        String[] cjFiles = { "C:\\Users\\MW\\Desktop\\Treasury process title and status\\1.txt", "C:\\Users\\MW\\Desktop\\Treasury process title and status\\2.txt", "C:\\Users\\MW\\Desktop\\Treasury process title and status\\3.txt", "C:\\Users\\MW\\Desktop\\Treasury process title and status\\4.txt", "C:\\Users\\MW\\Desktop\\Treasury process title and status\\5.txt" };

        int len = cjFiles.length;
        int attachmentTotalForEachZip = 0;
        int zipBatches = 0;
        if (len <= 10) {
            attachmentTotalForEachZip = 2;
            zipBatches = len / 2;
        } else {
            attachmentTotalForEachZip = 4;
            zipBatches = len / 4;
        }
        int total = 0;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;
        List<ZipOutputStream> zips = new ArrayList<ZipOutputStream>();

        for (int i = 0; i < cjFiles.length; i++) {
            if (total == 0) {
                zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            }
            total = total + 1;
            in = new FileInputStream(cjFiles[i]);
            File f = new File(cjFiles[i]);

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry((i + 1) + " - " + f.getName().substring(f.getName().indexOf("-") + 1, f.getName().length())));

            int length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();

            //download zip
            if (total == attachmentTotalForEachZip) {
                zips.add(zos);
                total = 0;
                zipBatches = zipBatches - 1;
            }

            // handle zip file amount (pdf total in each zip )
            if (zipBatches == 1) {
                attachmentTotalForEachZip = attachmentTotalForEachZip + (len % attachmentTotalForEachZip);
                zipBatches = 0;
            }
        }


        for (ZipOutputStream z : zips) {
            z.finish();
            z.close();
        }

    }
}
```

if there is any way to download all zip file.

Comment: You cannot download 2 separate files in one GET request.

Comment: Also this code is not written to download 2 files. You are writing multiple entries to one `ZipOutputStream`

Comment: thanks, can you recommend a solution to handle this case?

Comment: A solution to which problem?